# How can i write this javascript append(); better?

Tags: javascript, append

I've been learning javascript for a few weeks now and i'm getting my head around it relatively ok at the moment but i'm getting stuck on the "best practices" side of it.

For example, this append(); function. How can i write this better?

```
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[0][0]+','+cp[0][1]+','+cp[0][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[1][0]+','+cp[1][1]+','+cp[1][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[2][0]+','+cp[2][1]+','+cp[2][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[3][0]+','+cp[3][1]+','+cp[3][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[4][0]+','+cp[4][1]+','+cp[4][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[5][0]+','+cp[5][1]+','+cp[5][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[6][0]+','+cp[6][1]+','+cp[6][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[7][0]+','+cp[7][1]+','+cp[7][2]+');"></div>');
$("#swatches").append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[8][0]+','+cp[8][1]+','+cp[8][2]+');"></div>');
```

I know this is works, but i also know that there must be different and better ways to write this. I just don't know what it is :)

Any help/explanations would be massively appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Kyll , I've used StackOverflow for many things in the past and i know the knowledge level on here is massively higher than my own so i thought i'd just request some different examples of how t achieve the same results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop :

```
var swatches = $("#swatches");
for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) { 
    swatches.append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[i][0]+','+cp[i][1]+','+cp[i][2]+');"></div>');
}
```

Comment: This seems relatively simple enough for me to understand! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to iterate and append the html to the element.

```
var html = '';
 for(var i=0;i< 9; i++) {
    html += '<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb(' + cp[i][0] + ',' + cp[i][1] + ',' + cp[i][2] + ');"></div>'
 }

$("#swatches").append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you could assign `$('#swatches')` to variable so jQuery doesn't have to parse your `string` each time. Second, you can use `for` loop to reduce code length:

```
var swatches = $('#swatches');

for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    swatches.append('<div class="swatch" style="background-color:rgb('+cp[i][0]+','+cp[i][1]+','+cp[i][2]+');"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
function getColorString(rgb) {
    return 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
}

for (var i = 0; i < cp.length; i++) {
    $('<div>', {
        class: 'swatch',
        css: {
            backgroundColor: getColorString(cp[i])
        }
    }).appendTo('#swatches');
}
```